# El método borrar matriz no funciona

Tags: c#, array

Llevo unos dias con este ejercicio pero no consigo que el metodo borrarmatriz() me funcione, se que se me esta escapando algo pero no se el que, alguien puede orientarme?
No se como coger la matriz del main para utilizarla en borrarmatriz() y devolverla al Main

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

     int[,] matrizcreada = crearmatriz();

     Console.WriteLine("¿Desea borrar el contenido de alguna de las posiciones?\n" +
            "Pulse y + Enter para eliminar una entrada\n" +
            "Pulse cualquier tecla si no desea eliminar una entrada");
     char respuesta = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

     if (respuesta==121)
     {
          int[,] matrizmodificada = borrarmatriz(matrizcreada);

          Console.WriteLine("¿Desea borrar el contenido de otra posición?\n" +
            "Pulse y + Enter para eliminar una entrada\n" +
            "Pulse cualquier tecla si no desea eliminar una entrada");

     }
     else
     {
          Console.WriteLine("fin");
     }

}
static int[,] borrarmatriz(int[,]matriz)
{
     int[,] ematriz;
     int[,] matrizmodificada=int[,] ematriz;


     Console.WriteLine("¿Qué posición desea borrar?\n" +
            "inserte la fila y pulse Enter");
     int efila = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
     Console.WriteLine("inserte la columna");
     int ecolumna = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
     matrizmodificada[efila, ecolumna] = 0;

     return matrizmodificada;
}
```

Comment: Para que estas creando `ematriz`?

Comment: mi idea es que ematriz fuese la matriz con la posicion borrada y en un primer momento asignarle los valores de matrizmodificada, pero no me funciono

Comment: Claro. Pero ahora mismo estas eliminando la posicion en `matrizmodificada`, que es lo mismo que `ematriz`, y que por tanto está en blanco. Prueba a igualar `matrizmodificada` con `matriz` en tu método.

Comment: Madre mia.....acabo de hacer una prueba rapida a falta de modificar unas cosillas, pero parece que funciona.....
Muchisimas gracias, no hay nada como otros ojos para ver los fallos

Comment: @GabrielDelgado ahora solo falta que publiques tu respuesta correcta como una respuesta a tu propia pregunta amigo y cierras impecable!. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto, la respuesta correcta era

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

 int[,] matrizcreada = crearmatriz();

 Console.WriteLine("¿Desea borrar el contenido de alguna de las posiciones?\n" +
        "Pulse y + Enter para eliminar una entrada\n" +
        "Pulse cualquier tecla si no desea eliminar una entrada");
 char respuesta = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

 if (respuesta==121)
 {
      int[,] matrizmodificada = borrarmatriz(matrizcreada);

      Console.WriteLine("¿Desea borrar el contenido de otra posición?\n" +
        "Pulse y + Enter para eliminar una entrada\n" +
        "Pulse cualquier tecla si no desea eliminar una entrada");

 }
 else
 {
      Console.WriteLine("fin");
 }

}
static int[,] borrarmatriz(int[,]matriz)
{

 int[,] matrizmodificada=matriz;


 Console.WriteLine("¿Qué posición desea borrar?\n" +
        "inserte la fila y pulse Enter");
 int efila = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
 Console.WriteLine("inserte la columna");
 int ecolumna = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
 matrizmodificada[efila, ecolumna] = 0;

 return matrizmodificada;
}
```